# Cohomology exact sequence induced from exact sequence of coefficient

Tags: algebraic-topology

This might be a trivial question, but I was wondering if the following was true or not. Suppose that we have an exact sequence of groups $$0\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow K\rightarrow 0$$
Does it induce a long exact sequence in cohomology 
$$\cdots\rightarrow H^k(X;G)\rightarrow H^k(X;H)\rightarrow H^{k}(X;K)\rightarrow H^{k+1}(X;G)\rightarrow \cdots$$

Comment: What's an exact sequence of rings?

Comment: it should be groups

Comment: We can even assume that groups are abelian. Does it in fact induce a long exact sequence in cohomology?

Comment: Yes, for abelian groups (otherwise cohomology past $H^1$ is not well-defined). You can prove this by writing down a corresponding short exact sequence of chain complexes.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. I remembered hearing this result a while ago, but I just wasn't sure if I recalled it correctly.